# why doesn't off canvas code work in mobile?

Tags: javascript

I got this code from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav and it works fine in mobile as is. So simple, yet effective. But my usage doesn't work in my mobile or my customer's mobile.

console says:

(index):66 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
at openNav ((index):66)
at HTMLDivElement.onmouseover ((index):79)

**Would anyone like to hazard a guess as to why this doesn't work?**

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #96AD74;
  background-color: #9C836E;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #E2FAC0;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: darkblue;
  background: #808000;
  background: #7E6EB5;
  background: #FFAC1C;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  text-shadow: none;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" onmouseleave="closeNav();">
  <div class="pcc">MENU</div>
  <a href="index.php">home</a>
  <a href="coach.php">coaching</a>
  <a href="bio.php">biography</a>
  <a href="contact.php">contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: *"works fine in mobile. So simple, yet effective. But it doesn't work in my mobile"*   ---  Your statement is confusing .. First it works fine in mobile .. Then it doesn't work in your mobile ..

Comment: Thank you. I edited the text to make it clearer.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to close the menu when the user touches anything outside of it on a phone.

Add the following to your JavaScript file:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var mySidenav = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
    var openButton = document.getElementById("openButton");
    if (mySidenav.style.width == "250px" && !mySidenav.contains(e.target) && e.target != openButton) {
        closeNav();
    }
});
```

This will make it so when you click (touch) on any element besides the open button, it will close the sidebar.

Also, don't forget to set the ID of the element opening the navbar to "openButton", for example in the W3School tutorial you linked, you should modify it like this:

```html
<span id="openButton" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

Comment: No closing the side panel is not the issue. The problem is that it won't open!

Comment: Then you should clarify your question, because not working won't tell us what the problem is. Also, I didn't see your second edit either at the time of my answer, so I went with the information I had.